# jQuery.serializeArray() отправляет форму как строки "q[1][answers][]"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

Есть форма с чекбоксами

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q[1][answers][]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="q[1][answers][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="q[1][answers][]" value="2">

<input type="checkbox" name="q[2][answers][]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="q[2][answers][]" value="1">
```

Если отправить такую форму штатным образом, то через `$_POST` я получу массив из этих ключей

```
Array
(
    [q] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Проблема начинается, когда я пытаюсь отправить форму с помощью AJAX

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('form').on('submit', function(e){

    $.post( "<URL>", { answers: $(this).serializeArray() },

    function(response) {
     console.log(response);
    });

  });    
});
```

В таком случае на сервер приходит вид

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => q[0][answers][]
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => q[0][answers][]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => q[1][answers][]
            [value] => 1
        )

)
```

Как мне отправить форму `AJAX`ом так, что бы получить результат на сервере как при штатной отправке обычным POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post( "<URL>", $(this).serialize(),
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик
на сервер приходит "q[0][answers][]=0&q[0][answers][]=1&q[1][answers][]=1" строкой
var_dump(); выдает "string" а не "array", есть еще идеи?

Comment: всё, разобрался, parse_str() спасает, вопрос решен